# Use same Identity tables for .NET 4.5 and Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

The app I work on is a mix of Web Forms and MVC targeting .NET 4.5 and uses AspNet.Identity for logins, and we want to build new features on a new ASP.NET Core project using the same login tables (as well as maintain login/session state across apps, but that's a different issue). However, while testing this, I discovered that the ASP.NET Core Identity models for users, roles, etc. have new attributes that the old models/tables don't have.

How can I migrate these changes to the existing database so that the new app can point to the same tables for login/role data (without the old app losing any functionality, of course)?

Is it even possible for an asp.net app using Identity and an asp.net core app using Identity Core to make use of the same user tables?

**UPDATE**

I changed some code in a test version of the old app such that the Identity class implementations have all the properties of the new app. I can successfully create new logins on each (which populate the same table) and I can log into each, but User A created with App A cannot log into App B and vice versa. I get "Invalid login attempt" (a failed SignInResult) when I attempt logging into App A as User B and App B as User A.

As a side note, I have two ASP.NET apps pointing to the same Identity tables and not only can I log into each with the same credentials, but session state is maintained when I switch between them. My goal is to have the same functionality between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core.